# Place for text that uses by capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have text in my test

```
page.should have_content("File uploaded")
```

And in controller I have same text

```
flash[:notice] = "File uploaded"
```

Where I can store this text and refer to it in controller and test to not repeat myself and feel free to change it later in one place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use i18n keep text like this in `config/locales/en.yml` but I don't think this test/controller duplication of flash text is a DRY violation of the worst order.  However that's the place to keep it if you want it out of your controller.

In your en.yml:

```
en:
  upload_message: "File uploaded"
```

Now call with `I18n.t 'upload_message'`

Comment: Thanks. It's just I need. Actually it will helps me to keep such massages language-independent.